# Is there a way to make my window re-sizable in java?

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a custom window for my program, I cant seem to figure out how to add resizabilty.
I figured out movability but I just can't seem to get add resizabilty, any help would be amazing! Thank You in advance. I am trying to create a GUI library with more customizability than a standard JFrame.
Is there a way to make my window resizable in java?

```
/** *Code Updated*
* NOTE the frame is meant to be called from another class where the 
* contents will be added (buttons, etc.).
*/

package krypto.desktop.guiWindow;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class KFrame extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static JButton button = null;
private static JCheckBox checkBox = null;
private static JCheckBoxMenuItem checkBoxMenuItem = null;
private static JColorChooser colorChooser = null;
private static JComponent component = null;
private static JDesktopPane desktopPane = null;
private static JDialog dialog = null;
private static JEditorPane editorPane = null;
private static JFileChooser fileChooser = null;
private static JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = null;
private static JInternalFrame internalFrame = null;
private static JLabel label = null;
private static JLayeredPane layeredPane = null;
private static JMenu menu = null;
private static JMenuBar menuBar = null;
private static JMenuItem menuItem = null;
private static JOptionPane optionPane = null;
private static JPanel panel = null;
private static JPasswordField passwordField = null;
private static JPopupMenu popupMenu = null;
private static JProgressBar progressBar = null;
private static JRadioButton radioButton = null;
private static JRadioButtonMenuItem radioButtonMenuItem = null;
private static JRootPane rootPane = null;
private static JScrollBar scrollBar = null;
private static JScrollPane scrollPane = null;
private static JSeparator separator = null;
private static JSlider slider = null;
private static JSpinner spinner = null;
private static JSplitPane splitPane = null;
private static JTabbedPane tabbedPane = null;
private static JTable table = null;
private static JTextArea textArea = null;
private static JTextField textField = null;
private static JTextPane textPane = null;
private static JToggleButton toggleButton = null;
private static JToolBar toolBar = null;
private static JToolTip toolTip = null;
private static JTree tree = null;
private static JViewport viewport = null;
private static JWindow window = null;

private static boolean frameMovable = true;
private static boolean frameVisible = true;
private static boolean frameCenter = false;
private static boolean frameResizeable = true;
private static boolean exitMessage = false;

private static int frameSizeWidth = 400;
private static int frameSizeHeight = 300;
private static int frameMaxSizeWidth = 400;
private static int frameMaxSizeHeight = 300;
private static int frameMinSizeWidth = 400;
private static int frameMinSizeHeight = 300;
private static int frameLocationX = 50;
private static int frameLocationY = 50;

private static String minimizeIcon = "⎼";
private static String maximizeIcon = "▢";
private static String exitIcon = "X";

private static Color minimizeColor = Color.WHITE;
private static Color maximizeColor = Color.WHITE;
private static Color exitColor = Color.RED;
private static Color frameBackgroundColor = Color.DARK_GRAY;

private final javax.swing.JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public KFrame() {
    JButton buttonMinimize = createButtonMinimize();
    JButton buttonMaximize = createButtonMaximize();
    JButton buttonExit = createButtonExit();

    //if (frameCenter = true) {
    //TODO add Center to Screen
    //}

    //Exit Button
    buttonExit.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (exitMessage = false) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (exitMessage = true) {
            int confirm = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                    "Are You Sure to Close Application?", "Exit Confirmation",
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, javax.swing.JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null, null, null);
            if (confirm == javax.swing.JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });

    //Window Maximize/Normalize
    buttonMaximize.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (frame.getExtendedState() == JFrame.NORMAL) {
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        } else {
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
        }

    });

    //Minimize
    buttonMinimize.addActionListener(e -> frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED));

    javax.swing.JLabel buttonPanel = new JLabel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3, 5, 0));
    buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 25));
    buttonPanel.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    buttonPanel.add(buttonMinimize);
    buttonPanel.add(buttonMaximize);
    buttonPanel.add(buttonExit);

    GradientPanel titlePanel = new GradientPanel(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    if (frameMovable = true) {
        FrameDragListener frameDragListener = new FrameDragListener(frame);
        titlePanel.addMouseListener(frameDragListener);
        titlePanel.addMouseMotionListener(frameDragListener);
    }
    titlePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    titlePanel.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
    titlePanel.add(new JLabel(BorderLayout.WEST));
    titlePanel.add(new JLabel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    titlePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
    titlePanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    javax.swing.JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

    contentPanel.setBackground(frameBackgroundColor);

    try {
        contentPanel.add(button);
        contentPanel.add(checkBox);
        contentPanel.add(checkBoxMenuItem);
        contentPanel.add(colorChooser);
        contentPanel.add(component);
        contentPanel.add(desktopPane);
        contentPanel.add(dialog);
        contentPanel.add(editorPane);
        contentPanel.add(fileChooser);
        contentPanel.add(formattedTextField);
        contentPanel.add(internalFrame);
        contentPanel.add(label);
        contentPanel.add(layeredPane);
        contentPanel.add(menu);
        contentPanel.add(menuBar);
        contentPanel.add(menuItem);
        contentPanel.add(optionPane);
        contentPanel.add(panel);
        contentPanel.add(passwordField);
        contentPanel.add(popupMenu);
        contentPanel.add(progressBar);
        contentPanel.add(radioButton);
        contentPanel.add(radioButtonMenuItem);
        contentPanel.add(scrollBar);
        contentPanel.add(scrollPane);
        contentPanel.add(separator);
        contentPanel.add(slider);
        contentPanel.add(spinner);
        contentPanel.add(splitPane);
        contentPanel.add(tabbedPane);
        contentPanel.add(table);
        contentPanel.add(textArea);
        contentPanel.add(textField);
        contentPanel.add(textPane);
        contentPanel.add(toggleButton);
        contentPanel.add(toolBar);
        contentPanel.add(toolTip);
        contentPanel.add(tree);
        contentPanel.add(viewport);
        contentPanel.add(window);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }

    javax.swing.JPanel fatherPanel = new JPanel();
    fatherPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    fatherPanel.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    fatherPanel.add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frameSizeWidth, frameSizeHeight));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(frameMaxSizeWidth, frameMaxSizeHeight));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(frameMinSizeWidth, frameMinSizeHeight));
    frame.setUndecorated(true);

    //if (frameResizeable = true) {
    //
    //}

    frame.add(fatherPanel);
    frame.setLocation(frameLocationX, frameLocationY);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(frameVisible);
}

public static Color getMinimizeColor() {
    return minimizeColor;
}

public static void setMinimizeColor(Color minimizeColor) {
    KFrame.minimizeColor = minimizeColor;
}

public static Color getMaximizeColor() {
    return maximizeColor;
}

public static void setMaximizeColor(Color maximizeColor) {
    KFrame.maximizeColor = maximizeColor;
}

public static Color getExitColor() {
    return exitColor;
}

public static void setExitColor(Color exitColor) {
    KFrame.exitColor = exitColor;
}

public static int getFrameSizeWidth() {
    return frameSizeWidth;
}

public static void setFrameSizeWidth(int frameSizeWidth) {
    KFrame.frameSizeWidth = frameSizeWidth;
}

public static int getFrameSizeHeight() {
    return frameSizeHeight;
}

public static void setFrameSizeHeight(int frameSizeHeight) {
    KFrame.frameSizeHeight = frameSizeHeight;
}

public static boolean isFrameCenter() {
    return frameCenter;
}

public static void setFrameCenter(boolean frameCenter) {
    KFrame.frameCenter = frameCenter;
}

public static int getFrameLocationX() {
    return frameLocationX;
}

public static void setFrameLocationX(int frameLocationX) {
    KFrame.frameLocationX = frameLocationX;
}

public static int getFrameLocationY() {
    return frameLocationY;
}

public static void setFrameLocationY(int frameLocationY) {
    KFrame.frameLocationY = frameLocationY;
}

public static boolean isFrameResizeable() {
    return frameResizeable;
}

public static void setFrameResizeable(boolean frameResizeable) {
    KFrame.frameResizeable = frameResizeable;
}

public static boolean isFrameMovable() {
    return frameMovable;
}

public static void setFrameMovable(boolean frameMovable) {
    KFrame.frameMovable = frameMovable;
}

public static boolean isFrameVisible() {
    return frameVisible;
}

public static void setFrameVisible(boolean frameVisible) {
    KFrame.frameVisible = frameVisible;
}

public static Color getFrameBackgroundColor() {
    return frameBackgroundColor;
}

public static void setFrameBackgroundColor(Color frameBackgroundColor) {
    KFrame.frameBackgroundColor = frameBackgroundColor;
}

public static void JCheckBox(javax.swing.JCheckBox JCheckBox) {
    KFrame.checkBox = JCheckBox;
}

public static void JCheckBoxMenuItem(javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem JCheckBoxMenuItem) {
    KFrame.checkBoxMenuItem = JCheckBoxMenuItem;
}

public static void JColorChooser(javax.swing.JColorChooser JColorChooser) {
    KFrame.colorChooser = JColorChooser;
}

public static void JComponent(javax.swing.JComponent JComponent) {
    KFrame.component = JComponent;
}

public static void JDesktopPane(javax.swing.JDesktopPane JDesktopPane) {
    KFrame.desktopPane = JDesktopPane;
}

public static void JDialog(javax.swing.JDialog JDialog) {
    KFrame.dialog = JDialog;
}

public static void JEditorPane(javax.swing.JEditorPane JEditorPane) {
    KFrame.editorPane = JEditorPane;
}

public static void JFileChooser(javax.swing.JFileChooser JFileChooser) {
    KFrame.fileChooser = JFileChooser;
}

public static void JFormattedTextField(javax.swing.JFormattedTextField JFormattedTextField) {
    KFrame.formattedTextField = JFormattedTextField;
}

public static void JInternalFrame(javax.swing.JInternalFrame JInternalFrame) {
    KFrame.internalFrame = JInternalFrame;
}

public static void JLabel(javax.swing.JLabel JLabel) {
    KFrame.label = JLabel;
}

public static void JLayeredPane(javax.swing.JLayeredPane JLayeredPane) {
    KFrame.layeredPane = JLayeredPane;
}

public static void JMenu(javax.swing.JMenu JMenu) {
    KFrame.menu = JMenu;
}

public static void JMenuBar(javax.swing.JMenuBar JMenuBar) {
    KFrame.menuBar = JMenuBar;
}

public static void JMenuItem(javax.swing.JMenuItem JMenuItem) {
    KFrame.menuItem = JMenuItem;
}

public static void JOptionPane(javax.swing.JOptionPane JOptionPane) {
    KFrame.optionPane = JOptionPane;
}

public static void JPanel(javax.swing.JPanel JPanel) {
    KFrame.panel = JPanel;
}

public static void JPasswordField(javax.swing.JPasswordField JPasswordField) {
    KFrame.passwordField = JPasswordField;
}

public static void JPopupMenu(javax.swing.JPopupMenu JPopupMenu) {
    KFrame.popupMenu = JPopupMenu;
}

public static void JProgressBar(javax.swing.JProgressBar JProgressBar) {
    KFrame.progressBar = JProgressBar;
}

public static void JRadioButton(javax.swing.JRadioButton JRadioButton) {
    KFrame.radioButton = JRadioButton;
}

public static void JRadioButtonMenuItem(javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem JRadioButtonMenuItem) {
    KFrame.radioButtonMenuItem = JRadioButtonMenuItem;
}

public static void JRootPane(javax.swing.JRootPane JRootPane) {
    KFrame.rootPane = JRootPane;
}

public static void JScrollBar(javax.swing.JScrollBar JScrollBar) {
    KFrame.scrollBar = JScrollBar;
}

public static void JScrollPane(javax.swing.JScrollPane JScrollPane) {
    KFrame.scrollPane = JScrollPane;
}

public static void JSeparator(javax.swing.JSeparator JSeparator) {
    KFrame.separator = JSeparator;
}

public static void JSlider(javax.swing.JSlider JSlider) {
    KFrame.slider = JSlider;
}

public static void JSpinner(javax.swing.JSpinner JSpinner) {
    KFrame.spinner = JSpinner;
}

public static void JSplitPane(javax.swing.JSplitPane JSplitPane) {
    KFrame.splitPane = JSplitPane;
}

public static void JTabbedPane(javax.swing.JTabbedPane JTabbedPane) {
    KFrame.tabbedPane = JTabbedPane;
}

public static void JTable(javax.swing.JTable JTable) {
    KFrame.table = JTable;
}

public static void JTextArea(javax.swing.JTextArea JTextArea) {
    KFrame.textArea = JTextArea;
}

public static void JTextField(javax.swing.JTextField JTextField) {
    KFrame.textField = JTextField;
}

public static void JTextPane(javax.swing.JTextPane JTextPane) {
    KFrame.textPane = JTextPane;
}

public static void JToggleButton(javax.swing.JToggleButton JToggleButton) {
    KFrame.toggleButton = JToggleButton;
}

public static void JToolBar(javax.swing.JToolBar JToolBar) {
    KFrame.toolBar = JToolBar;
}

public static void JToolTip(javax.swing.JToolTip JToolTip) {
    KFrame.toolTip = JToolTip;
}

public static void JTree(javax.swing.JTree JTree) {
    KFrame.tree = JTree;
}

public static void JViewport(javax.swing.JViewport JViewport) {
    KFrame.viewport = JViewport;
}

public static void JWindow(javax.swing.JWindow JWindow) {
    KFrame.window = JWindow;
}

public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}

public static boolean isExitMessage() {
    return exitMessage;
}

public static void setExitMessage(boolean exitMessage) {
    KFrame.exitMessage = exitMessage;
}

public static int getFrameMaxSizeWidth() {
    return frameMaxSizeWidth;
}

public static void setFrameMaxSizeWidth(int frameMaxSizeWidth) {
    KFrame.frameMaxSizeWidth = frameMaxSizeWidth;
}

public static int getFrameMaxSizeHeight() {
    return frameMaxSizeHeight;
}

public static void setFrameMaxSizeHeight(int frameMaxSizeHeight) {
    KFrame.frameMaxSizeHeight = frameMaxSizeHeight;
}

public static int getFrameMinSizeWidth() {
    return frameMinSizeWidth;
}

public static void setFrameMinSizeWidth(int frameMinSizeWidth) {
    KFrame.frameMinSizeWidth = frameMinSizeWidth;
}

public static int getFrameMinSizeHeight() {
    return frameMinSizeHeight;
}

public static void setFrameMinSizeHeight(int frameMinSizeHeight) {
    KFrame.frameMinSizeHeight = frameMinSizeHeight;
}

public void JButton(javax.swing.JButton JButton) {
    KFrame.button = JButton;
}

@SuppressWarnings("DuplicatedCode")
private javax.swing.JButton createButtonMinimize() {
    javax.swing.JButton button = new JButton(minimizeIcon);
    button.setForeground(minimizeColor);
    button.setBorderPainted(false);
    button.setBorder(null);
    button.setFocusable(false);
    button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    return button;
}

@SuppressWarnings("DuplicatedCode")
private javax.swing.JButton createButtonMaximize() {
    javax.swing.JButton button = new JButton(maximizeIcon);
    button.setForeground(maximizeColor);
    button.setBorderPainted(false);
    button.setBorder(null);
    button.setFocusable(false);
    button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    return button;
}

@SuppressWarnings("DuplicatedCode")
private javax.swing.JButton createButtonExit() {
    javax.swing.JButton button = new JButton(exitIcon);
    button.setForeground(exitColor);
    button.setBorderPainted(false);
    button.setBorder(null);
    button.setFocusable(false);
    button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    return button;
}

public String getMinimizeIcon() {
    return minimizeIcon;
}

public static void setMinimizeIcon(String minimizeIcon) {
    KFrame.minimizeIcon = minimizeIcon;
}

public String getMaximizeIcon() {
    return maximizeIcon;
}

public static void setMaximizeIcon(String maximizeIcon) {
    KFrame.maximizeIcon = maximizeIcon;
}

public String getExitIcon() {
    return exitIcon;
}

public static void setExitIcon(String exitIcon) {
    KFrame.exitIcon = exitIcon;
}

private static class GradientPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public GradientPanel(Color background) {
        setBackground(background);
    }

    //Gradient Support
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (isOpaque()) {
            Color background = new Color(49, 46, 46);
            Color controlColor = new Color(49, 46, 46);
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            Paint oldPaint = g2.getPaint();
            g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, background, width, 0, controlColor));
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            g2.setPaint(oldPaint);
        }
    }
}

public static class FrameDragListener extends MouseAdapter {

    private final JFrame frame;
    private Point mouseDownCompCoords = null;

    public FrameDragListener(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseDownCompCoords = null;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        assert e != null;
        mouseDownCompCoords = e.getPoint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        assert e != null;
        Point currCoords = e.getLocationOnScreen();
        frame.setLocation(currCoords.x - mouseDownCompCoords.x, currCoords.y - mouseDownCompCoords.y);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't think you'd need to _add resizeability_.  Rather,  just _don't add fixed-sizedness_.  Are you perhaps setting the `maximumSize` and `minimumSize` of the window the same?

Comment: Pleas use [Java naming conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/)

Comment: What environment are you operating in?  You might actually have little-to-no control over your window's size.  For instance, have you ever seen and Android app that _doesn't_ take over the entire screen?  MacOS was like that too, back in the day (might still be, for all I know...)

Comment: You are using variables with the same names as the objects they represent. There are reasons for naming conventions that forbid this (the Java naming convention had classes start with upper case letters and variables start with lower case letters). If only because of your disregard of this I would hate to have to debug your code. I'm not being nasty, your naming scheme makes it difficult for me to see what is a variable and what is a class.

Comment: You made the frame 'undecorated" so there are no borders to grab and resize the frame. Also, you should NOT be using static variables.

Comment: *NOTE* the frame is meant to be called from another class where the contents will be added (buttons, etc.).                                                                                                                             
c0der and NomadMaker I've fixed most of the issues.                                                                                                      camickr the point is to make my own custom frame.                                                          @KevinAnderson I am using IntelliJ on Ubuntu. also, I was using prefered size.

Comment: Please check out the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).  Especially the part about `static` variables and methods.  You should not be using them like that.